# Using Google Scripts to search and to match array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to build button with a dialog box to match the result using script. For example, I divided US into East, Middle and West. I have a text file named US 50 states name and abbreviation. When I type "NY" or Boston", the result would show "East". How can I achieve this in Google Spreadsheet.Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I typed this code but there is no place to search. Where I can search? In other words, do I have to add button to show call this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the script file:

```
function findSection(state)
{
  var state =(typeof(state) != 'undefined')?state: '';
  var found = "No Data Provided";
  if(state)
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht = ss.getSheetByName('StateSearch');
    var rng = sht.getDataRange();
    var rngA = rng.getValues();
    found ='Not Found';
    for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      if((state==rngA[i][0]) || (state == rngA[i][1]))
      {
        found = rngA[i][2];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}

function searchSideBar()
{
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sectionSearchDialog').setTitle('State Search');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

This is the HTML file for the sidebar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    State:<input type="text" id="txt1" size="30" value=""/><br />
    Section:<input type="text" id="txt2" size="30" value=""/><br />
    Search:<input type="button" value="Search" onClick="sectionSearch();" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      console.log('here');
      function sectionSearch()
      {
        var v = $('#txt1').val();
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSection)
          .findSection(v);
      }
      function updateSection(v)
      {
        $('#txt2').val(v);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what the Spreadsheet "StateSearch' looks like: you can put the state data here and in the third column you can add your section names if you wish.  Adding the cities is left as an exercise for the reader.

[image]

A simple way to add some cities without Geo Location might be this way:

Same sidebar code: this script file:

```
function findSection(state)
{
  var state =(typeof(state) != 'undefined')?state: '';
  var found = "No Data Provided";
  if(state)
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht = ss.getSheetByName('StateSearch');
    var rng = sht.getDataRange();
    var rngA = rng.getValues();
    found ='Not Found';
    for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      if((state==rngA[i][0]) || (state == rngA[i][1]) || (isACity(state,rngA[i][3])>-1))
      {
        found = rngA[i][2];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}

function searchSideBar()
{
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sectionSearchDialog').setTitle('State Search');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function isACity(city,cities)
{
  var city = (typeof(city) != 'undefined')?city:'';
  var cities = (typeof(cities) != 'undefined')?cities:'';
  var r = -1;
  if(city && cities)
  {
    var citiesA = String(cities).split(',');
    r = citiesA.indexOf(city);
  }
  return r;
}
```

The spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

You have to run the sidebar code to load it or you can do that in an onOpen().